# How to send IMSI instead of MSISDN in a USSD Request

Tags: gateway, ussd, restcomm

I am working on restcomm ussd gateway trying to send a Push USSD Request. I used the example shipped with the source (HTTPush) to send it. Looking at the captured packets, the gateway first sends SRI MAP and gets routing information from the HLR, then it sends the ussd request but it gets rejected by the HLR with InvalidDestinationReference error. I spoke to the guys and they said you should set the IMSI as the destination reference instead of the MSISDN in the USSD request. Anyways, I looked back at the packets again and found that the IMSI is sent back to the gateway along with the routing information but the gateway set the MSISDN as the destination reference when it send the USSD request. My question is, is there anyway to tell the restcomm API to set the IMSI instead of the MSISDN in the ussd request?

Regards
Sleem